# isolated scope directive cause error on karma

Tags: javascript, angularjs, karma-runner

I have a directive with isolates scope in which I pass a binded property
`"="`:

```
.directive('drawCircle',function (){
  return {
    restrict:'A',
    replace:false,
    scope:{
      point:'=',
    },
    template:' <circle '+
    'ng-attr-cx="{{point[0]}}" ng-attr-cy="{{point[1]}}" '+
    'r="3" fill="purple" />'
  };
 });
```

I use it:

```
 <g draw-circle point="[22,33]">
```

it works fine in the browser but karma throws:

```
Error: [$compile:multidir] Multiple directives [drawCircle (module: myApp), drawCircle (module: myApp)]
asking for new/isolated scope on: <g draw-circle="" point="p">
```

---

here's the piece of unit test that's creating the error:

```
 describe('directives testing', function() {
 var element, scope, compiled;

beforeEach(module('draw.path'));

  describe('draw-single-point directive',function(){
          beforeEach(inject(function($rootScope,$compile){

              scope = $rootScope.$new();
              element = angular.element('<g draw-circle point="p" ></g>');
              compiled = $compile(element);
              scope.p=[110,11];
              compiled(scope);

              scope.$digest();
          }));


  });
```

Why does Karma complain ?

Comment: Which version of angular you use? Beside I'd say karma is correct, and for some reason the error isn't shown in your app

Comment: I'm using angular v1.4.8

Comment: @maurycy you're saying because both ng-repeat and my custom directive create an  isolated scope , right?

Comment: Now that I looked at your code again you don't even have `ngRepeat` in karma test, and the error says there are to directives `drawCircle` requesting isolated scope on the element

Comment: @maurycy it'supposed to work even without ng-repeat

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is possible issue you are facing

Your directive `drawCircle` is defined/loaded twice and thats the exact error you would get if that happens - check that pen: http://codepen.io/maurycyg/pen/pgWyEy?editors=101

I don't see any problems with your test code or directive or even using the directive together with ng-repeat so I'd suggest checking KARMA configuration, maybe you load directive twice

Comment: the problem is this is only happening in karma, in my browser it looks like this http://codepen.io/maio/pen/rxGLoR

Comment: That's what I'm saying, check your karma config and tests if you don't add the directive twice. Have you checked my codepen?

Comment: that was it !! karma.conf.js was catching also the non compiled version, thanks